# publishing an app flavor as a single app

Tags: java, android

i have created two flavor of app using following in gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
}    

productFlavors 
{

free {

    versionName "1.0-free"
    buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "false"
    buildConfigField "String", "BuildType", "Free"
}
paid {
    versionName "1.0-paid"
    buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "true"
    buildConfigField "String", "BuildType", "Paid"
}
}
```

and in java using like this

```
public void manageFeaturesWithBuildType()
    {
        String buildType = BuildConfig.BuildType;
        if(buildType.equals("Paid"))
        {
            //Here Enable or Disable your features for paid Build
        }
        else
        {
            //Here Enable or Disable your features for free Build
        }
    }
```

now i created a signed apk for both free-relese.apk and paid-release.apk
i want to publish it on playstore
i want to make it as both paid and free versions

how can i publish it?
Do I need to publish paid-release apk or free-release.apk or both?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify two different `applicationId` for each flavors if you like to have the paid version to be separate from your free version.

```
free {
   applicationId "com.example.myapp.free"
}
```

&

```
paid {
   applicationId "com.example.myapp.paid"
}
```

or you could simplify above with using `applicationIdSuffix ".free"` and remove `applicationId` from the flavors

Comment: which apk i need to publish paid-relese.apk or free-release apk??

Comment: obviously you wanna publish them both then why having two different apks? 
Free will be downloaded free. 
Paid users have to pay for it through play store. 
P.S: I'm in no position to tell you what to do with your app.

Comment: i mean which flavor need to sign when using sign apk

Comment: according to their names, both are signed and both can be distributed separately